# Word corrupt rendering, contains part of interface

Tags: microsoft-word, documents, microsoft-word-2016, rendering

A couple of old documents have stopped rendering correctly on `Word 2016 version 1708 (build 8431.2079) MSO (16.0.8431.2046) 32-bits`. I also tested this on `Word 2013 (15.0.4841.1000) MSO (15.0.4541.1000) 64-bits`, and there the document does work perfectly fine.

I suspect it's not a problem with the document itself, as the render changes when I scroll/zoom in and it even contains parts of the interface that shouldn't  appear in the document at all. For example, the following page appears to contain a part of the "measurement tape" that's at the top of the screen:

[image]

And here part of the paragraph properties widget appears:

[image]

In reading mode, the document looks fine:

[image]

The file I took those screenshots from: https://ufile.io/mrevh (feel free to suggest a better file sharing service).

What could be the cause of this issue? Is there something I can do about it? Word is already at the most recent version.

Comment: Please post one such document for testing.

Answer (score 1):

I have downloaded and looked at your document using Word 2016 and I can see
no problem.
Here is [my image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5RTx.jpg) of your example page
for comparison. So something is wrong on your computer.

What I can suggest :

- [Start Word in Safe mode](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Open-Office-apps-in-safe-mode-on-a-Windows-PC-dedf944a-5f4b-4afb-a453-528af4f7ac72)
  If this works, then the problem is with some Office add-on,
  which you will have to uninstall or reconfigure.
  See how to
  [View, manage, and install add-ins in Office programs](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/View-manage-and-install-add-ins-in-Office-programs-16278816-1948-4028-91E5-76DCA5380F8D).
- Repair Office 2016 in *Control Panel* -> *Programs and Features*,
  by right-click on Microsoft Office 2016, and choosing Change.
  Try first Quick Repair, and if the problem continues, Online Repair.
- If the above didn't solve the problem, uninstall and reinstall Office.

Comment: I tried both repairs, I tried reinstalling and I also tried copying the content to a new document, non of which worked. Opening in safe mode did, and after that normal mode started working as well. I'll take a look at the add-ons and try to remove the offending one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I tried the repairs, I reinstalled Office, I copied the content into a new document, all in vain.

I opened the document in safe mode, and the problem did not occur, a syou predicted. After that, opening it again in normal mode was successful as well! I left the add-ins as they were. I do not understand what happened, but the issue seems to be solved.

Thanks!

Comment: If you plan to provide an answer to the question, format your text as such, emphasizing on the solution, and if you only want to say thanks, a comment is enough.